# Callback fails in Symfony2 service

Tags: php, symfony, callback

I'm using the [`PHP-FineDiff`](https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff) class  as a service in my project.  Creating diff works fine, however, when I try to restore the diffs using e.g. `FineDiff::renderToTextFromOpcodes()`, nothing happens.

I digged a little in the code and found that a callback doesn't work.  After commenting out some

```
if ( !is_callable($callback) ) {
    return;
}
```

I run into the error:

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'FineDiff' not found in /var/www/sopos-blog/src/Sopos/WikiBundle/Services/FineDiff.php line 321.

These are some relevant lines of code:

```php
public static function renderToTextFromOpcodes($from, $opcodes) {
    ob_start();
    FineDiff::renderFromOpcodes($from, $opcodes, array('FineDiff','renderToTextFromOpcode'));
    return ob_get_clean();
}

// ...

public static function renderFromOpcodes($from, $opcodes, $callback) {
    if ( !is_callable($callback) ) {
        return;
        }
    $opcodes_len = strlen($opcodes);
    $from_offset = $opcodes_offset = 0;
    while ( $opcodes_offset <  $opcodes_len ) {
        $opcode = substr($opcodes, $opcodes_offset, 1);
        $opcodes_offset++;
        $n = intval(substr($opcodes, $opcodes_offset));
        if ( $n ) {
            $opcodes_offset += strlen(strval($n));
            }
        else {
            $n = 1;
            }
        if ( $opcode === 'c' ) { // copy n characters from source
            call_user_func($callback, 'c', $from, $from_offset, $n, '');
            $from_offset += $n;
            }

// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your class's FQCN is `Sopos\WikiBundle\Services\FineDiff`, so the callback must be one these:

```
$arrayCallback = array(__NAMESPACE__.'\FineDiff','renderToTextFromOpcode');
$stringCallback = __NAMESPACE__.'\FineDiff::renderToTextFromOpcode';
```

You could also replace `__NAMESPACE__` by the real namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 is not able to autoload the class `FineDiff`. Add the namespace to the callback:

```
public static function renderToTextFromOpcodes($from, $opcodes) {
  ob_start();
  FineDiff::renderFromOpcodes($from, $opcodes, array(__NAMESPACE__.'\FineDiff','renderToTextFromOpcode'));
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```